# Как исправить ошибку "Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of undefined"

Tags: javascript

```js
let menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item');
document.ul.insertBefore(menu[2], menu[1]);
console.log(menu[2]);
console.log(menu[1]);
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menu-item">Первый пункт</li>
      <li class="menu-item">Третий пункт</li>
      <li class="menu-item">Второй пункт</li>
      <li class="menu-item">Четвертый пункт</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="column"></div>
<div class="column">
  <div class="title" id="title">
    Мы продаем только технику Apple
  </div>
  <div class="adv">
    Это назойливая реклама, которую нужно удалить
  </div>
  <div class="prompt" id="prompt">
  </div>
</div>
```

код ошибки:

> script.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of
>   undefined

но при console.log получаю:

```
<li class="menu-item">Третий пункт</li>
<li class="menu-item">Второй пункт</li>
```

Comment: Сразу говорю учусь работать с javascript так что для профессионалов это мб очень легко ,в инете ответ не нашёл.

Comment: откуда ты взял `document.ul`?

Comment: я понимаю что тут ошибка но в чём мне надо просто заменить элемент

Comment: так и получи этот элемент. в твоему случае `document.ul`  возвращает `undefined`, поэтому и был вопрос, почему ты решил, что это вернет что-то еще

Comment: да но почему я тогда получаю нужные мне элементы при console.log()?

Comment: через консоль лог ты из выводишь, а не получаешь. Получаешь их ты выше, получай подобный образом и `ul` и ошибки не будет

Comment: нет если я правильно понимаю menu=document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item'); я получаю нужные элементы значит ошибка в document.ul но как исправить то? можешь просто 1 строчку кинуть в ответ я оценю.

Comment: тут ты получил `li`, а `undefined` у тебя `document.ul`. который ты никак не получаешь

Comment: можно кодом? просто походу не понимаю

Comment: А в чем суть...??  Даже Если ты правильно захватишь `ul`, у тебя результат не измениться...

Comment: или так `document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0]` или `document.querySelector('ul')`...

Comment: мне надо просто поменять местами <li></li> я вроде получаю их как надо а взять их из массива не могу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cannot read property '...' of undefined
>
> Не удаётся прочитать свойство '...' из неопределённого

В представленном вами коде, даже не определен объект `document.ul`, но вас это не останавливает и вы пытаетесь обратиться к методу `insertBefore` неопределенного (undefined) объекта.

---

```js
const menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item');

menu[0].parentNode.insertBefore(menu[2], menu[1]);
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">Первый пункт</li>
  <li class="menu-item">Третий пункт</li>
  <li class="menu-item">Второй пункт</li>
  <li class="menu-item">Четвертый пункт</li>
</ul>
```

---

- `menu[0]` - первый элемент из [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName);
- `menu[0].parentNode` - родительский [элемент](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).

Добавляем элемент `menu[2]` в список дочерних к родителю `menu[0].parentNode` после элемента `menu[1]` при помощи [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore):

```
menu[0].parentNode.insertBefore(menu[2], menu[1]);
```

Если такой элемент уже существует, то просто сменится его позиция в DOM дереве.

Comment: заработало но можете объяснить эту строчку menu[0].parentNode.insertBefore(menu[2], menu[1]);(что значит  parentNode и почему сначала идёт menu[0])

Comment: а почему ответ сделал общим?